# Connecting to a remote SQL Server in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I have a Windows Server 2019 I use RDP to remote into and access a SQL Server via SSMS. On my local machine, I am trying to create a connection manager in SSIS so I can pull data from this server.

In SSIS, I added an OLE DB source to my page and under provider I am only seeing Native OLE DB under which I selected Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. I input my information and I get the error:

> server does not exist or access is denied

Comment: On your local machine, you need to be able to talk to the remote SQL Server. You get to solve credentials and networking to do this. Credentials: Domain user, SQL server, Azure AD entity are your options here. If it's not SQL Server, then you get to ensure is "my computer" on the same domain as "remote computer"?  Knowing all that, then you get to solve network. Can a request from local computer get through the ethernet to talk to SQL Server on a specific port and do all the traffic cops allow that communication to go through? Update your Q with some of the details and we can further assist.

Comment: If you need rdp to get to sql server you won't be able to connect to it directly, unless someone opens a direct connection to it. Otherwise there would be no point to RDPing